# ExtJS 6.x Add Custom Click Event To Component For ViewController

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

For ExtJS 6.5+ Modern, how do you add a click event to an component so that you can access it in a view controller.

The example below doesn't work.  I have also tried adding a listener directly to the sub-element.

Example Template:

```
Ext.define('TestController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.test-controller',

    control: {
        '[reference=someComponent]': {
            click: 'someComponentClick'
        }
    },

    someComponentClick: function() { 
       console.log('it worked!')
    }
})


Ext.define('TestContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'test-container',
    controller: 'test-controller',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'component',
            reference: 'someComponent'
            html: 'CLICK HERE TO TEST'
        }
    ]
})
```

**Update**

Based on priyadarshi answer, the following on the element calls the function in the controller.  I would prefer however to pick the event up normally in the controller by just listening to the click event.   Is there anyway to attach event listeners to the dom from the controller or at least fire an event from the element so that you can pick it up in the controller (without it explicitly calling functions on the controller).

```
 Ext.define('TestController', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
     alias: 'controller.test-controller',

     control: {
         '[reference=someComponent]': {
             click: 'someComponentClick'
         }
     },

     someComponentClick: function() { 
        console.log('it worked!')
     },
     someFuncOnController: function() {
         console.log('someFuncOnController') // << This runs
     }
 })


 Ext.define('TestContainer', {
     extend: 'Ext.Container',
     xtype: 'test-container',
     controller: 'test-controller',
     items: [
         {
             xtype: 'component',
             reference: 'someComponent'
             html: 'CLICK HERE TO TEST',
             listeners: [
                 element: 'element',
                 click: 'someFuncOnController'
             ]
         }
     ]
 })
```

Comment: Don't use control() statements on the controller.

Comment: why shouldn't I use control? that's typically how i do my listeners on a component

Comment: Because it has to setup events on an event bus that need to process all events. If you use an event directly on the component it's a simple O(1) lookup in the controller.

Comment: Why does the controller have to process all events.. the control lists out the events it wants.. it can simply just attach listeners to the appropriate events/elements.. or is this not how it works?

Comment: That's not how events at the controller level work.

Comment: have you read the docs for [Ext.app.Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.Controller.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering your code.

Do you need something like this?

```
Ext.define('TestController', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

 init: function() {
     this.control({
         'test-container': {
             buttonClicked: this.onButtonClick
         }
     });
 },

 onButtonClick: function(button) { 
    console.log('it worked!')
 }
})


Ext.define('TestContainer', {
 extend: 'Ext.Container',
 xtype: 'test-container',
 //controller: 'test-controller', //declare your controller in your app.js
 items: [
     {
         xtype: 'button',
         text: 'Click Me!'
         listeners: {
             tap: function (button) {
                 var container = button.up('test-container');
                 container.fireEvent('buttonClicked', button);
             }
         }
     }
 ]
})
```

Comment: This is not as nice as being able to just use control directly without having to modify the view, but this definitely works.

Comment: you can capture the event using something like `'button[itemId=btnClick]'` but i would stick with this approach. It's more elegant imho.

(add `itemId: 'btnClick'` to the button inside your view)

Answer (score 4):

In ExtJS **[`6.x`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html)** we don't need to provide `reference` or `control` like below code

```
control: {
        '[reference=someComponent]': {
            click: 'someComponentClick'
        }
    }
```

When a **[`view controller`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html)** is specified on a view, events and other handlers that use strings as values will be automatically connected with the appropriate methods in the controller's class.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2au2)**, I have created a demo using [`view`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.Panel.html#cfg-controller) and [`view controller`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html). This show better explanation for events. I hope this will help you or guide you.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.define('MyViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myview',

    // This method is called as a "handler" for the Add button in our view
    onAddClick: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Button Click');
    },
    // This method is called as a "click" for the component in our view
    onComponentClick: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Component Click');
    },
    // This method is called as a "click" for the label in our view
    onLabelClick: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Label Clcik');
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    controller: 'myview',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add',
        handler: 'onAddClick', // calls MyViewController's onAddClick method
    }, {
        xtype: 'component',
        margin: 10,
        style:"padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;cursor: pointer;",
        html: 'Component->click here to test {component} click',
        listeners: {
            element: 'element',
            click: 'onComponentClick' // calls MyViewController's someFuncOnController method
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        margin: 10,
        style:"padding: 10px;border: 1px solid #38839d;cursor: pointer;",
        html: 'Label Component->click here to test {label} click',
        listeners: {
            element: 'element',
            click: 'onLabelClick' // calls MyViewController's onLabelClick method
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Maybe needless to say, but: mind the quotes for the callback method (`'onComponentClick'`)! Without them an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Containers do not have a click event. You need to target the DOM element to attach the event. Do something like this.

```
      var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      html: 'Click Me!',
      listeners: {
        click: function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success!', 'I have been clicked!')  
          }
        }
     });

    container.getEl().on('click', function(){ 
      this.fireEvent('click', container); 
    }, container);
```

Comment: Based on priyadarshi answer, the following on the element calls the function in the controller.  I would prefer however to pick the event up normally in the controller by just listening to the click event.   Is there anyway to attach event listeners to the dom from the controller or at least fire an event from the element so that you can pick it up in the controller (without it explicitly calling functions on the controller).

Comment: Yes, it can be done. I will post the code in sometime. I am currently on mobile device.